# Outlook 2010 Categories - External mailbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange, tags

At my work multiple people use the same mailbox. Incoming mails are tagged with different categories to show who is currently working on one of the mails.

There seems to be some delay however when tagging a mail with a category before the other users will be able to see it.

Is there any way to speed up the refresh rate of this?
The mailbox seems to work fine otherwise and mails come in as soon as they're sent.

Answer (score 1):

You can improve email categorization in general and make it automatic. Not sure if you already use some email administration tool, but you may be interested in CodeTwo Exchange Rules Pro that gives you an extensive control of your correspondence. It's equipped with advanced keywords filters and you can [set an automatic forward, auto-reply etc](http://www.codetwo.com/exchange-rules-pro/?sts=1189). It's been used in our company for 6 months and work like a charm in our case as we also use it to automatically stamp our e-mails with signatures, disclaimers, rotating banners etc. I hope it's a helpful info.